# React native - How to get the path to an asset image/video

Tags: react-native

I really only need this for a video, I'm using the video component https://github.com/yamill/react-native-videoplayer and I want to use a local asset video rather than an mp4 stored on the web, how would I locate the video? e.g. http://local/my-asset/video.mp4 (This is obviously made up for demo purposes).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend switching to react-native-video. It has better support 
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video

Then, the video component's source can be passed as follows:

```
<Video source={{uri: "http://local/my-asset/video.mp4"}
    ...
</Video>
```